# Flutter ClipPath Shadow

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a flutter container who's top edge is slanted, and additionally has a shadow following the slanted edge. It feel's like there should be a simple enough solution, but after experimenting with lots of different online articles and stack overflow posts, I still have not been able to produce this.
I've been using Clip Path to create the container that I need. Is there a simple way to create a shadow around the ClipPath?

Comment: Maby you can use a Card as it's parent and define shadow for the card.

Comment: check `ShapeBorder` class, not `ClipPath`

Comment: Do you have any examples of it's usage? That's one of the solutions I tried to research but the examples I found on line didn't seem to compile anymore

Comment: for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/57943257/2252830 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/59286474/2252830

Comment: Can you include an image and your code snippet ?